# QTP/VBScript: How to remove all URLs from a string?

Tags: regex, vbscript, replace, qtp

I have a string in my QTP test project.  In some cases, this string is a plaintext E-mail's content; in other cases it's HTML.  In both cases, I need to strip all URLs from the string to match it against an Expected case.

How can this be done in QTP/VBScript?

Comment: Several questions have been asked here already that had something to do with matching a URL with regex. I suggest you do a Google search for "regex url site:stackoverflow.com" to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, though your URLs will need to begin with http:// or https:// for them to be picked up:

```
Dim text
text = "<your text with URLs here>"

Dim rgx
Set rgx = New RegExp
rgx.IgnoreCase = True
rgx.Global = True
rgx.Pattern = "([A-Za-z]{3,9})://([-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@{1})?([-A-Za-z0-9\.]+)+:?(\d+)?((/[-\+~%/\.\w]+)?\??([-\+=&;%@\.\w]+)?#?([\w]+)?)?"

Dim match, matches
Set matches = rgx.Execute(text)
For Each match in matches
  MsgBox match.Value, 0, "Found Match"
Next
```

The regex pattern for matching URLs comes from [Chris Freyer's blog](http://elearning.lse.ac.uk/blogs/clt/?p=285) and seems to handle most types of URL you're likely to encounter. It worked well on the tests I performed with it.